# Photoshop wrap around edges blur

Tags: adobe-photoshop, blur

Ho to blur the image, with as much less effort as possible, so the blur wraps around the edges

I want to blur HDRI maps

Comment: Do you want to get a dark halo effect as on HDRI images?

Comment: Do you have any examples you can show us of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The effect you are looking for might be called "vignette". Search for that and see if it helps. If not, show us some screenshots of what you want to achieve.

Comment: I think this is about a blurring operation, when applied to pixels on e.g. the left-hand edge of the canvas, having an effect on the pixels on the right hand edge of the canvas. HDRI maps would normally be wrapped into a sphere or hemisphere, so this might be required to prevent causing a visible 'seam'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Duplicate your original image into a new layer.
2. Add guides to edges of original image.
3. Enlarge your canvas by 200%.
4. Duplicate the image to all eight neighboring sides to make seamless tiling.
5. Apply blur of choice.
6. Crop your canvas down to original size.
7. You now have wrapping blur with no hard edges!

[image: Seamless blur]